# Is there a way to use a pyaudio in python 3.8?

Tags: python, pyaudio

Please provide a solution regarding this I tried the pipwin approach its not working and if anyone know how to create a virtual environment  of 3.7 for u sing pyaudio can share idea would be a great

Answer (score 0):

You can create virtual environment using(If you have anaconda installed)

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.7
```

then you can use

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) link to download .whl file according to the python version it supports.

Go to the following directory and run this command on command prompt (Windows here) .

`C:\Users\jay_p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts>pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39m-win64.whl`

(This may be different for you.)